# How to Access Laravel app from another PC/Phone

Tags: laravel, networking, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have windows 10 and WSL ubuntu. I used to run

```
php artisan serve
```

from my ubuntu(WSL). Now I want to access my laravel app from other devices. Should I run

```
 php artisan serve --host <IP ADDR> --port 80
```

from ubuntu terminal or should I run it in windows CMD? and which IP should I use? I see different IP from my ubuntu terminal(WSL) as compare to the IP addr from the windows CMD. I don't know what to use. 
I already tried to run the code from CMD but I still can't access the app.

Comment: `--host 0.0.0.0`. Chances are you'll need `sudo` to bind to port 80, and the other devices will have to be on the same network.

Comment: you can use IPV4 in any system't browser under the same network to access the laravel app, for example - http://192.168.1.11:8080 , where 192.168.1.11 is IPV4

Comment: what do you mean on --host 0.0.0.0? @ceejayoz

Comment: php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80

Comment: @MDB I mean exactly what I typed. Use `--host 0.0.0.0` to do what you want. Where you've written `--host <IP ADDR>`.

Comment: and the how can i access it on other device? what should i type in the url bar?

Comment: what is your IPv4 Address? of the machine you are running laravel app

Comment: @MDB You'd enter the IP address of the server running `php artisan serve`. Again, this only works if you're on the same internal network (or if the server is on the public internet). Alternatively, install Ngrok.io.

Comment: @SachinVairagi 192.168.1.3

Comment: @ceejayoz i am new to this sir. Please enlighten me. Should Ngrok.io works on windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

You should follow these steps:

1:  Run artisan command like this:

```
php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
```

2:  In your other device you should run first your pc `IP` `address` and then `colon` and port number like this:

`10.0.56.23:8000`